# Deciphering DataKind type promotion in Servant library

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, servant

I am trying to gork the [tutorial](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for the [servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.7) library, a type-level web DSL. The library makes extensive use of the [`DataKind`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html) language extension.

Early in that that tutorial we find the following line which defines a web service end point:

```
type UserAPI = "users" :> QueryParam "sortby" SortBy :> Get '[JSON] [User]
```

I don't understand what it means to have string and arrays in a type signature.  I am also unclear what the tick mark (`'`) means in front of `'[JSON]`.

So my questions boil down to what is the type/kind of the string and arrays, and how is this [later](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html) interpreted when it is turned into a WAI end point?

---

As a side note, the consistent use of `Nat` and `Vect` when describing `DataKinds` leave us with a frustratingly limited set of examples to look at when trying to understand this stuff. I think I've read through that example at least a dozen times at different places and I still don't feel like I understand what is going on.

Comment: Do a bit of programming in a dependently-typed language like Agda or Idris, and that will give you a solid toolset for doing type-level programming like here. Much better than just reading about `Nat` and `Nat`-indexed `Vect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `DataKinds` turned on, you get new types that are automatically created based on regular data type definitions:

- If you have `data A = B T | C U`, you now get a new kind `A` and new types `'B :: T -> A` and `'C :: U -> A`, where `T` and `U` are the new kinds of the similarly lifted `T` and `U` types
- If there is no ambiguity, you can write `B` for `'B` etc.
- Type-level strings all share the same kind `Symbol`, so you have e.g. `"foo" :: Symbol` and `"bar" :: Symbol` as valid types.

In your example, `"users"` and `"sortby"` are both types at kind `Symbol`, `JSON` is an (old-fashioned) type at kind `*` (defined [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.7/docs/Servant-API-ContentTypes.html#t:JSON)), and `'[JSON]` is a type at kind `[*]`, i.e. it is a singleton type-level list (it is equivalent to `JSON ': '[]` the same way `[x]` is equivalent to `x:[]` in general).

The `[User]` type is a regular type at kind `*`; it is simply the type of lists of `User`s. It is not a singleton type-level list.

Answer (score 14):

### Let's build a Servant

#### Goals

Our goals will be Servant's goals:

- Specify our REST API as a single type `API`
- Implement the service as one single side-effectful (read: monadic)
  function
- Use real types to model resources, only serializing to a lesser type
  at the very end e.g. JSON or Bytestring
- Obey the common WAI (Web Application Interface) interface that most
  Haskell HTTP frameworks use

#### Crossing the threshold

Our initial service will simply be a `/` that returns a list of
`User`s in JSON.

```
-- Since we do not support HTTP verbs yet we will go with a Be
data User = ...
data Be a
type API = Be [User]
```

Though we have yet to write a single line of value-level code, we have
already sufficiently represented our REST service – we have simply
cheated and done it at the type level. This feels exciting to us and,
for the first time in a long time, we are hopeful about web
programming again.

We will need a way to convert this to a WAI `type Application =
Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`.
There is not enough room to describe how WAI works. The basics: we are
given a request object and a way to construct response objects, and we
are expected to return a response object. There are lots of ways of
doing this, but a simple choice is this.

```
imp :: IO [User]
imp =
  return [ User { hopes = ["ketchup", "eggs"], fears = ["xenophobia", "reactionaries"] }
         , User { hopes = ["oldies", "punk"], fears = ["half-tries", "equivocation"] }
         ]

serve :: ToJSON a => Be a -> IO a -> Application
serve _ contentIO = \request respond -> do
  content <- contentIO
  respond (responseLBS status200 [] (encode content))

main :: IO ()
main = run 2016 (serve undefined imp)
```

And this actually works. We can run this and curl it and get the
expected response back.

```
% curl 'http://localhost:2016/'
[{"fears":["xenophobia","reactionaries"],"hopes":["ketchup","eggs"]},{"fears":["half-tries","equivocation"],"hopes":["oldies","punk"]}]%
```

Notice that we never constructed a value of type `Be a`. We used
`undefined`. The function itself ignores the parameter altogether.
There actually is no way of constructing a value of type `Be a` since
we never defined any data constructors.

Why even have `Be a` parameter? The poor simple truth is that we need
that `a` variable. It tells us what our content type will be, and it
lets us set up that sweet Aeson constraint.

Code: [0Main.hs](https://gist.github.com/hlian/c90b9b7bf845255292fb65d41f43ad21).

### :<|>s in the road

Now we challenge ourselves to devise a routing system, where we can
have separate resources at separate places in the fake URL folder
hierachy. Our goal will be to support this type of service:

```
type API =
       "users" :> Be [User]
  :<|> "temperature" :> Int
```

To do this, we will first need to turn on the `TypeOperators` and the
`DataKinds` extensions. As detailed in @Cactus's answer, data kinds
allows us to store data at the type level and GHC comes built-in with
type-level string literals. (Which is great since defining strings at
type level is not my idea of fun.)

(We will also need `PolyKinds` so GHC can kind-infer this type. Yes we
are deep in the heart of extensions jungle now.)

Then, we need to conjure clever definitions for `:>` (the subdirectory
operator) and `:<|>` (the disjunction operator).

```
data path :> rest
data left :<|> right =
  left :<|> right

infixr 9 :>
infixr 8 :<|>
```

Did I say clever? I meant dead simple. Notice that we have given
`:<|>` a type constructor. This is because we will glue our monadic
functions together to implement a disjunction and ... oh it's just
easier to given an example.

```
imp :: IO [User] :<|> IO Int
imp =
  users :<|> temperature
  where
    users =
      return [ User ["ketchup", "eggs"] ["xenophobia", "reactionaries"]
             , User ["oldies", "punk"] ["half-tries", "equivocation"]
             ]
    temperature =
      return 72
```

Now let us turn our attention to the special problem of `serve`. No
longer can we write a function `serve` that relies on the API being a
`Be a`. Now that we have a little DSL at the type level for RESTful
services, it would be nice if we could somehow pattern match on the
types and implement a different `serve` for `Be a`, `path :> rest`,
and `left :<|> right`. And there is!

```
class ToApplication api where
  type Content api
  serve :: api -> Content api -> Application

instance ToJSON a => ToApplication (Be a) where
  type Content (Be a) = IO a
  serve _ contentM = \request respond -> do
    content <- contentM
    respond . responseLBS status200 [] . encode $ content
```

Note the usage of associated data types here (which in turn require us
to turn on either `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs`). Though a `Be a` endpoint
has an implementation with type `IO a`, this will not be sufficient to
implement disjunction. As underpaid and lazy functional programmers we
will simply throw another layer of abstraction and define a type-level
function called `Content` that takes a type `api` and returns a type
`Content api`.

```
instance Exception RoutingFailure where

data RoutingFailure =
  RoutingFailure
  deriving (Show)

instance (KnownSymbol path, ToApplication rest) => ToApplication (path :> rest) where
  type Content (path :> rest) = Content rest
  serve _ contentM = \request respond -> do
    case pathInfo request of
      (first:pathInfoTail)
        | view unpacked first == symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy path) -> do
            let subrequest = request { pathInfo = pathInfoTail }
            serve (undefined :: rest) contentM subrequest respond
      _ ->
        throwM RoutingFailure
```

We can break down the lines of code here:

- We guarantee a `ToApplication` instance for `path :> rest` if the
  compiler can guarantee that `path` is a type-level symbol (meaning
  it can [among other things] be mapped down to a `String` with
  `symbolVal`) *and* that `ToApplication rest` exists.
- When the request arrives, we pattern match on `pathInfos` to to
  determine success. On failure, we will do the lazy thing and throw
  an unchecked exception in `IO`.
- On success, we will *recurse at the type level* (cue laser noises
  and fog machine) with `serve (undefined :: rest)`. Note that `rest`
  is a "smaller" type than `path :> rest`, much like how when you
  pattern match on a data constructor you end up with a "smaller"
  value.
- Before recursing we whittle down the HTTP request with a convenient
  record update.

Note that:

- `type Content` function maps `path :> rest` to `Content rest`.
  Another form of recursion at the type level! Also note that this
  implies that an extra path in the route does not change the type of
  the resource. This matches our intuition.
- Throwing an exception in IO is not Great Library Design™, but I will
  leave it up to you to fix that problem. (Hint:
  `ExceptT`/`throwError`.)
- Hopefully we are slowly motivating the usage of `DataKinds` here
  with string symbols. Being able to represent strings at the type
  level has enabled us to use types to pattern match routing at the
  type level.
- I use lenses to pack and unpack. It is just faster for me to hack up
  these SO answers with lenses, but of course you could just use
  `pack` from the `Data.Text` library.

All right. One more instance. Breathe. Take a break.

```
instance (ToApplication left, ToApplication right) => ToApplication (left :<|> right) where
  type Content (left :<|> right) = Content left :<|> Content right
  serve _ (leftM :<|> rightM) = \request respond -> do
    let handler (_ :: RoutingFailure) =
          serve (undefined :: right) rightM request respond
    catch (serve (undefined :: left) leftM request respond) handler
```

In this instance we

- Guarantee `ToApplication (left :<|> right)` if the compiler can
  guarantee blah blah blah you get it.
- Introduce another entry in the `type Content` function. Here is the
  line of code that lets us build up to a type of `IO [User] :<|> IO
  Int` and have the compiler successfully break it up in the course of
  instance resolution.
- Catch the exception we threw above! When an exception happens on the
  left, we go to the right. Again, this is not Great Library Design™.

Run [1Main.hs](https://gist.github.com/hlian/c90b9b7bf845255292fb65d41f43ad21) and you should be able to `curl` like this.

```
% curl 'http://localhost:2016/users'
[{"fears":["xenophobia","reactionaries"],"hopes":["ketchup","eggs"]},{"fears":["half-tries","equivocation"],"hopes":["oldies","punk"]}]%

% curl 'http://localhost:2016/temperature'
72%
```

### Give and take

Now let us demo a usage for type-level lists, another feature of
`DataKinds`. We will augment our `data Be` to store a list of types
that the endpoint can give out.

```
data Be (gives :: [*]) a

data English
data Haskell
data JSON

-- | The type of our RESTful service
type API =
       "users" :> Be [JSON, Haskell] [User]
  :<|> "temperature" :> Be [JSON, English] Int
```

Let us also define a typeclass that matches the list of what types an
endpoint can give with the list of MIME types that the HTTP request
can accept. We will use `Maybe` to denote failure here. Again, not
Great Library Design™.

```
class ToBody (gives :: [*]) a where
  toBody :: Proxy gives -> [ByteString] -> a -> Maybe ByteString

class Give give a where
  give :: Proxy give -> [ByteString] -> a -> Maybe ByteString
```

Why two separate typeclasses? Well, we need one for the kind `[*]`,
which is the kind for a list of types, and one for the kind `*`, which
is the kind of just a single type. Just like you cannot define a
function that takes for an argument something that is both a list and
a non-list (as it will not type-check), we cannot define a typeclass
that takes for an argument something that is both a type-level list
and a type-level non-list (as it will not kind-check). If only we had
kindclasses...

Let's see this typeclass in action:

```
instance (ToBody gives a) => ToApplication (Be gives a) where
  type Content (Be gives a) = IO a
  serve _ contentM = \request respond -> do
    content <- contentM
    let accepts = [value | ("accept", value) <- requestHeaders request]
    case toBody (Proxy :: Proxy gives) accepts content of
      Just bytes ->
        respond (responseLBS status200 [] (view lazy bytes))
      Nothing ->
        respond (responseLBS status406 [] "bad accept header")
```

Very nice. We use `toBody` as a way of abstracting out the computation
of converting the value of type `a` into the underlying bytes that WAI
wants. On failure we will simply error out with 406, one of the more
esoteric (and therefore more fun to use) status codes.

But wait, why use type-level lists in the first place at all? Because
as we did before we are going to pattern-match on its two
constructors: nil and cons.

```
instance ToBody '[] a where
  toBody Proxy _ _ = Nothing

instance (Give first a, ToBody rest a) => ToBody (first ': rest) a where
  toBody Proxy accepted value =
    give (Proxy :: Proxy first) accepted value
      <|> toBody (Proxy :: Proxy rest) accepted value
```

Hopefully this sort of makes sense. Failure occurs when the list runs
empty before we find a match; `<|>` guarantees we will short-circuit
on success; `toBody (Proxy :: Proxy rest)` is the recursive case.

We will need some fun `Give` instances to play with.

```
instance ToJSON a => Give JSON a where
  give Proxy accepted value =
    if elem "application/json" accepted then
      Just (view strict (encode value))
    else
      Nothing

instance (a ~ Int) => Give English a where
  give Proxy accepted value =
    if elem "text/english" accepted then
      Just (toEnglish value)
    else
      Nothing
    where
      toEnglish 0 = "zero"
      toEnglish 1 = "one"
      toEnglish 2 = "two"
      toEnglish 72 = "seventy two"
      toEnglish _ = "lots"

instance Show a => Give Haskell a where
  give Proxy accepted value =
    if elem "text/haskell" accepted then
      Just (view (packed . re utf8) (show value))
    else
      Nothing
```

Run the server again and you should be able to `curl` like this:

```
% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/users' -H 'Accept: application/json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:10 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

[{"fears":["xenophobia","reactionaries"],"hopes":["ketchup","eggs"]},{"fears":["half-tries","equivocation"],"hopes":["oldies","punk"]}]%

% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/users' -H 'Accept: text/plain'
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:11 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

bad accept header%

% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/users' -H 'Accept: text/haskell'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:14 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

[User {hopes = ["ketchup","eggs"], fears = ["xenophobia","reactionaries"]},User {hopes = ["oldies","punk"], fears = ["half-tries","equivocation"]}]%

% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/temperature' -H 'Accept: application/json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:26 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

72%

% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/temperature' -H 'Accept: text/plain'
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:29 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

bad accept header%

% curl -i 'http://localhost:2016/temperature' -H 'Accept: text/english'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 06:56:31 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.2

seventy two%
```

Hooray!

Note that we have stop using `undefined :: t` and switched to `Proxy
:: Proxy t`. Both are hacks. Calling functions in Haskell lets us
specify values for value parameters but not types for type parameters.
A sad asymmetry. Both `undefined` and `Proxy` are ways of encoding
type parameters at the value level. `Proxy` is able to do it with no
runtime cost *and* the `t` in `Proxy t` is poly-kinded. (`undefined`
has type `*` so `undefined :: rest` would not even kind-check here.)

#### Remaining work

How can we get all the way to a full Servant competitor?

- We need to break `Be` up into `Get, Post, Put, Delete`. Note that
  some of these verbs also now take *in* data in the form of a request
  body. Modeling content types and request bodies at the type level
  requires similar type-level machinery.
- What if the user wants to model her functions as something besides
  `IO`, such as a stack of monad transformers?
- [A more precise, yet more complicated, routing algorithm.](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/blob/a551eb6/servant-server/src/Servant/Server/Internal/RoutingApplication.hs#L41)
- Hey, now that we have a type for our API, would it be possible to
  generate a *client* of the service? Something that makes HTTP
  requests to a service obeying the API description rather than
  creating the HTTP service itself?
- Documentation. Making sure everybody understands what all these
  type-level hijinks are. ;)

### That tick mark

> I am also unclear what the tick mark (') means in front of '[JSON].

The answer is obscure and stuck in [GHC's manual in section 7.9](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html).

> Since constructors and types share the same namespace, with promotion you can get ambiguous type names. In these cases, if you want to refer to the promoted constructor, you should prefix its name with a quote.
>
> With -XDataKinds, Haskell's list and tuple types are natively promoted to kinds, and enjoy the same convenient syntax at the type level, albeit prefixed with a quote. For type-level lists of two or more elements, such as the signature of foo2 above, the quote may be omitted because the meaning is unambiguous. But for lists of one or zero elements (as in foo0 and foo1), the quote is required, because the types [] and [Int] have existing meanings in Haskell.

This, how verbose all the code we had to write above was, and much else besides is due to how type-level programming is still a second-class citizen in Haskell unlike in dependently-typed languages (Agda, Idris, Coq). The syntax is weird, the extensions are many, the documentation is sparse, the errors are nonsense, but boy oh boy type-level programming is fun.

Comment: Great answer! This can be complemented with [implementing a minimal version of haskell servant](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/11/implementing-a-minimal-version-of-haskell-servant/) and [Servant, Type Families, and Type-level Everything](http://www.arow.info/blog/posts/2015-07-10-servant-intro.html).